# Android Google Maps v2 API showing blank grid - I've check manifest already

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm having the same problem that a lot of people are, the google maps api is not working. I've checked my manifest here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycqs.lbs"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mycqs.lbs.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- import the library com.google.android.maps!!! -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I used the keytools command to get the SHA1 code and turned on the Google Maps Android API v2 service, entered the code followed by my package name, and entered the apiKey into the mapview xml. But I'm still getting a blank screen. Any ideas?